# Core Data Attributes

Tags: ios, core-data

If I'm making an Entity in Core Data to handle possible values a person can select in a questionnaire form do I have to create an attribute for every possible selectable question? For example my Entity named Person has attributes for name, date, time, and than a bunch of possible answers to select radio-button style that should be added to the Person Entity. Is it better to use a separate Entity for the questionnaire portion.

**Edit for better clarity:**

The app/survey form is a list of questions with a radio button style check box. If the question applies to them they touch the circle button and it fills in the circle. So its a boolean value. However I'm just not sure if I have to make each one of those questions an boolean attribute or not? This seems like a simple enough project to start learning Core Data which is the purpose of using Core Data instead of some other modeling and persistence solution.

Comment: Need some more information, your problem is not clear. Are the potential answers same across all questions (yes, no, n/a) or individual questions with unique answers?

Comment: Is it one questionnaire shown once to the individual app user? If so, you can use user defaults to save the answers.

Comment: @Shades yes. Its is one questionnaire shown once to the individual app user. The user defaults is a good idea, however I was wanting to use this simple project to start learning Core Data in the process. So I was wondering if I actually needed to create an attribute for every possible answer. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: So you want to have a questionnaire with multiple questions, each question can have one of multiple answers (how flexible should it be) and multiple people can take the questionnaire and answer whichever subset of questions they choose?

Comment: @Wain the questionnaire is just a list of questions not multiple choice if the question applies to you then you check the radio button next to the question. If it doesn't apply to you you would leave the radio button unchecked and skip the question essentially and continue down the list.

Comment: So I've added an answer based on your comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Separating** the two entities is a good idea as it **avoids confusion** and keeps your code cleaner. When you step away from the project and return to it 4 months later, there will be no issues discerning where data is saved and from where to retrieve it.

Your **Person** entity will have its attributes (name, email, etc) and the **Questionnaire** entity will have its attributes- **yes**, one for **each** question with a **Boolean** type.

Answer (score 1):

If your properties are y/n answers, that would be boolean attribute e.g.:

Person.licensed = y/n

If your properties have more than y/n possible answer you might use a number attribute:

Person.licensed = 1(y), 0(n), -1(Unknown), -2(Ineligible)

You may need more flexible properties. Maybe there are many types of licenses:

Person.licenses --> Related Entity License with attributes- license.type, license.issueDate, license.expireDate

Then, if you are doing something like a survey, there are many other potential paths. You'll need to elaborate on what you are doing for more help.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. It is just check the box that applies type of thing. It is either yes or no. Boolean value. If they select an answer that applies to them the radio button changes from empty to filled. But I'm not sure if I have to create an attribute for each of those questions or not.

Comment: It's the simplest way, I'd say so. You could be more flexible with a related entity, but in my experience, your Core Data fetches, sorts, and predicates are going to be much easier if you keep it in that "flat file" style. unless you want to mix up questions, create new on the fly, and/or filter them as applicable only for certain persons, I would just add the attributes. Make the default = False or, if you want to track unanswered state, use no default.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment you don't need a Boolean or any other attribute. You have a set of questions, which are just instances in the data store. You could group them into a questionnaire if you want, which would be another entity and a relationship between them. Your person is another entity, and has a to-many relationship to question. As the user ticks questions that apply to them you add those questions to the relationship.